# Play 2.3 request2session still not compiling

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, migration, playframework-2.3

I am trying to migrate from Play 2.2.2 to Play 2.3.1 and followed the official migration guide http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23

After changing in my view template

```
@if(session.get("username") != null) { 
    ... 
}
```

to

```
@if(request2session.get("username") != null) { 
    ...
}
```

I still get the compiler error:

```
not found: value request2session
```

Do I have to import this explicitly? The migration guide says nothing about it. After searching the web everyone says replace session by request2session and you'll be fine. But this does not work for me??? Btw I'm using Play with Java 6.

Comment: What implicit parameters do you have ? An `implicit request: RequestHeader` should make work a `@request.session.get("xx")`.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. Didn't know that I have do declare implicit parameters explicitly. Didn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: I would like to jump in and say that i'm currently running Play! 2.4.6 and I was getting the same compilation error when using `session.get("xx")` but doing `request.session.get("xx")` does work. Oh, and `request2session` does work for me though. Could anyone explain?